# php: round minutes up to the nearest quarter hour, then do more

Tags: php, ceil

The initial problem is this: 
Take the amount of minutes -> turn into quarter hours -> 1 quarter hour is 1 unit -> output units

I've been putting a page together all day today and my brain just stopped working a couple of minutes ago and I just can't wrap my head around how to output the amount of units.  I knew posting the problem on this site would help.

So the user puts in the amount of minutes (not hours and minutes, just minutes) and the site needs to output the amount of units. A unit is a quarter hour.  The minutes are always rounded up to the nearest quarter hour. I know I'll use ceil in some sort of way and probably(?) number_format, but I just can't get it to come out correctly.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$units = ceil($minutes / 15)
```

Comment: wow, I was making it way more hard than it actually was.  that worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this:

`return (round($minutes / 15) * 15) % 60;`

Produces:

```
for($i=0; $i<60; $i++) {
    echo $i . ' -> ' . roundQuarter($i) . '<br/>';
}

function roundQuarter($minutes) {
    return (round($minutes / 15) * 15) % 60;
}

0 -> 0
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 0
4 -> 0
5 -> 0
6 -> 0
7 -> 0
8 -> 15
9 -> 15
10 -> 15
11 -> 15
12 -> 15
13 -> 15
14 -> 15
15 -> 15
16 -> 15
17 -> 15
18 -> 15
19 -> 15
20 -> 15
21 -> 15
22 -> 15
23 -> 30
24 -> 30
25 -> 30
26 -> 30
27 -> 30
28 -> 30
29 -> 30
30 -> 30
31 -> 30
32 -> 30
33 -> 30
34 -> 30
35 -> 30
36 -> 30
37 -> 30
38 -> 45
39 -> 45
40 -> 45
41 -> 45
42 -> 45
43 -> 45
44 -> 45
45 -> 45
46 -> 45
47 -> 45
48 -> 45
49 -> 45
50 -> 45
51 -> 45
52 -> 45
53 -> 0
54 -> 0
55 -> 0
56 -> 0
57 -> 0
58 -> 0
59 -> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rounded = floor($minutes / 15);

1 minute / 15 = 0.0666 -> 0
14 minute / 15 = 0.9333 -> 0;
15 / 15 = 1 -> 1;
```

This'll give you 0->3 for the range of 15 minute periods. If you want 1-4, then use `ceil()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not do the trick?

```
$numberOfMinutes = 135;

$numberOfFifteenMinuteUnits = round($numberOfMinutes / 15);

echo $numberOfFifteenMinuteUnits;
```